# Using Router for web and RouterExtensions for mobile in a single component

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to code share in my project between a web and mobile app version.

I have a component that requires programmatic navigation and therefore I need to inject the Angular Router (from '@angular/router') for the web version and NativeScript RouterExtensions (from '@nativescript/angular') for the mobile version. Is there a recommended way to "dynamically" inject a dependency into a component, so that each target that is compiled for gets the correct dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first step you should create an injection token

```
// src/app/tokens.ts
import {InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';

export const UNIVERSAL_ROUTER = new InjectionToken<string>('Custom router');
```

After that in your module which is related to web application (I assume it is `app.module.ts`) you define it in your providers list

```
// src/app/app.module.ts
...
import {Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {UNIVERSAL_ROUTER} from '~/app/tokens';

@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        {provide: UNIVERSAL_ROUTER, useExisting: Router},
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Simultaneously you define this token as a `RouterExtension` in the module which states for mobile application (i.e. `app.module.tns.ts`):

```
// src/app/app.module.tns.ts
...
import {NativeScriptRouterModule, RouterExtensions} from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import {UNIVERSAL_ROUTER} from '~/app/tokens';

@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        {provide: UNIVERSAL_ROUTER, useClass: RouterExtensions},
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Having this done, you can inject router by means of `@Inject` decorator like

```
constructor(@Inject(UNIVERSAL_ROUTER) private router) {}
```

and get a platform-specific router wherever you need it.